# Realm, Configuration and app groups

Tags: swift, realm, ios-app-group

I'd like to use Realm with app groups to be able to share data with watch extension. I'm facing problem, that when I try to configure default realm.. By that I mean that I create new path and then I create new configuration. So far so good, but when I try to set this configuration as defaultConfiguration, nothing happens. For better idea check screenshot where is my code plus console output. Any idea? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defaultConfiguration` you set on `Realm.Configuration` is used to initialize new Realms. So if you would print the path of a `Realm` instance, e.g. `try! Realm().path`, then this would reflect the path from the shared app group. You did instead initialize a new & fresh configuration, which always uses the initial default values.